# Daily compound aggregation of Django's ``User`` models' ``date_joined`` field (for graphing with Highcharts)

Tags: django, date, graph, aggregate, highcharts

I would like to take my `User` model and break it down by day, using the `date_joined` field. Django's [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) seems to be a good fit, but im not sure how to use this with a DateField object. I believe I also want the values to compound.

My goal is to get a whole number for each day since the very first signup to the most present (and continuing). I *think* I want this in compound form, so for example, if the first day i have 100 signups and the day after is 80, I want the second days total to be 180. This way I can see the userbase grow/drop over time and not just see signup spikes and then flatline on days that there are no signups.

Pretty set on using Highcharts for the graphing. Here is a live example of the graph I wish to implement, only using Apple stock data but it's more or less what I want, only with daily amounts of user signup. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

I can build a QuerySet of a single instance with the following example. This isn't a very realistic approach going forward though. I'd like to dynamically calculate these figures, not manually assign them.

`y2007m09d01=(user_list.filter(date_joined__year="2007").filter(date_joined__month="9").filter(date_joined__day="1").count())

y2007m09d02=(user_list.filter(date_joined__year="2007").filter(date_joined__month="9").filter(date_joined__day="1").count() + y2007m09d01)`

Comment: Another approach would be to first figure out the earliest datetime on record. Using that datetime as a starting point, iterate through every single day (till present day), each time doing a filter for <= that day and counting it.... May take a long time to run but that would probably be fairly easy to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some "all django" solution to this, but if not you can just use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) over the list of users. I'm thinking something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

iter_groups = groupby(User.objects.all(), attrgetter('date_joined'))
groups = [list(g) for _, g in iter_groups]
```

Comment: This gives me a nice result but im unsure how to reference each groups date_joined. I suppose it's possible to reference one of the containing users ``date_joined`` field, as they will all be the same (within a group). Let me work on this some more and see.

Comment: Well, in my example I assumed you only wanted the groups list, but the `_` in `list(g) for _, g in iter_groups` stands for the date_joined of each group, you can change the comprehension to pack the results the way it better suits you.

Comment: Im having a hard time wrapping my head around that last line. Is there a less compact way to express this? I now understand the use of ``_`` but im unsure how to expand this. Further more, I would like to take the last result, with each pass, and add the total so far... e.g. ``[100, 110, 150, 154, ...]`` as appose to ``[100, 10, 40, 4, ...]``

Comment: I suggest you play around with it in the django shell, until you figure out how to use the result of the groupby (that's what I did). As for the adding of the previous elements, you can do it separately once you get the totals of each group.

Comment: Getting there. After a bunch of trial and error I now have ``groups = [dict({_:len(list(g))}) for _, g in iter_groups]`` which outputs ``{datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 16, 9, 54, 31): 1}...`` now I have to work on compounding the totals.